# COC popup style in neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

recently I started using (neo)vim.
I downloaded (neo)vim and copy-pasted [this](https://gist.github.com/benawad/b768f5a5bbd92c8baabd363b7e79786f) init.vim and the [coc-settings.json](https://gist.github.com/benawad/e187dd887f256a6a002905ec7f22ad76).
([Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnupOrSEikQ) is the video about the config.)
Everything works as it should, but coc's popup is a bit... yeah.
On the first pic is my coc popup window.
On the second pic is how it should look like.

How can I change the style to the second one?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running `nvim-qt` it's

```
:GuiPopupmenu 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!